# How combine the flatmap and previous Single

Tags: rx-java, kotlin, reactive-programming

There is next working code, which combine results of `.connect()` and `.auth()`.

`auth()` depends on the result of `connect()`. In total it necessary to combine api and auth results into `Connection` object.

```
fun getConnection(token: String): Single<Connection> {
  return connect()
            .map { Api(it) }
            .flatMap { api -> api.auth(token)
                                 .map { Connection(api, it) }
                     }     
}
```

IMHO this code is smelling. May be it has more optimal solution for getting `Connection` without an internal mapping in rxjava2?

Comment: I find it returns Single. So I think all methods return `Single`. The code is not bad smell.

Comment: You can improve by naming the lambda parameters explicitly instead of `it`. It is not recommended to use `it` when lambdas are nested or types are not obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you don't actually need to use `map()` at all. Just create your `Api` object within `flatmap()`.

```
fun getConnection(token: String): Single<Connection> {
  return connect().flatMap { conn ->
    val api = Api(conn)
    api.auth(token).map { Connection(api, it) }
  }     
}
```